# Stuck on a bubble sort (only using while loops) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
def bubble_sort(alist):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i<len(alist):
        while j<(len(alist)-1-i):
            if alist[j]>alist[j+1]:
                temp = alist[j]
                alist[j] = alist[j+1]
                alist[j+1] = temp
            j = j+1

        i = i + 1
    return alist 

abc = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
alist1 = bubble_sort(abc)
print(alist1)
```

I have no idea why this only undergoes one pass. Can someone pls help??

Comment: Shouldn't you be resetting `j` at some point?

Comment: Use `for i in range(n)` loop instead of `while` with `i+1`. Also python is smart enough to swap vars by `a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to move the initialization `j=0` inside the first while loop, as follows. Note that you can also swap two values in a shorter way in Python, as I did:

```
def bubble_sort(a):
    i = 0
    while i<len(a):
        j = 0
        while j<(len(a)-1-i):
            if a[j]>a[j+1]:
                a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]
            j = j+1  
        i = i + 1
    return a 

abc = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
alist1 = bubble_sort(abc)
print(alist1)   # [17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]
```

Comment: Thnx tons mate!